# Manually modify master-bin.index

Tags: replication, mariadb

I have an issue with MariaDB Server 5.5.56 replication. The slave got stuck and when I realized that we had already lost some of the bins. So this is the scenario :

In master :

MariaDB [(none)]> show binary logs;
+-------------------+------------+
| Log_name          | File_size  |
+-------------------+------------+
| master-bin.000320 | 1073742333 |
| master-bin.000321 | 1074247558 |
| master-bin.000322 |  753717941 |
| master-bin.000323 |  883803465 |
+-------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

cat master-bin.index
./master-bin.000320
./master-bin.000321
./master-bin.000322
./master-bin.000323

In slave ( excerpt )

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
              Master_Log_File: master-bin.000312
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 405852801
               Relay_Log_File: mariadb-relay-bin.000942
                Relay_Log_Pos: 405852988
        Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000312
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 405852703
              Relay_Log_Space: 405853426
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1236
                Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

So my idea to try and recover the slave is :

1.- In master : stop mariadb service
2.- In master : copy from backup bins 312 to 319
3.- In master : manually add bins 312 to 319 to master-bin.index
4.- In master : start mariadb service
5.- In slave : start slave

Would that work ? Is there any other way to solve my problem ? I know manually modifying master-bin.index is not recommended but I can not think of any other alternative to avoid recreating the slave.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**The best advice would be to rebuild the slave.** Missing 8 binary logs means you may be missing a lot of transactions. Another option would be to execute CHANGE MASTER to and move to the next available binary log. You may need to skip slave errors along the way until the slave 'catches up' BUT you have to use pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync to "resync" the data between these nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think "Missing 8 binary logs" is accurate for this scenario. I do have those logs, what I'm trying to do here is mysql to acknowledge them so the replica can resume from where it left ( it is stuckat this moment )

Comment: @Bertran we had lost some of the bins. I may have misunderstood you then

Comment: yes, we "had" lost them in prod but still have them in a backup but restoring them in place seems not to be enough because master-bin.index don't have them listed

Comment: @Bertran - Then how did `master-bin.000312` get changed to `master-bin.000320`?  If you have reloaded the missing 8 files, then edit the file containing the list of binlogs.  (It's format is rather obvious.)

Comment: @RickJames we have a retention of ten days so after the slave got stuck the master kept rolling. The slave was stuck for almost 2 months so when we realized that we had already lost some logs. I restored them froma backup and what I'm asking is if it is safe to manually edit and change master-bin.index to add those lines. Is it clear the situation ?

Comment: @Bertran - For a 10-day retention period, you must check more often than 10 days; else there is no recover.  (Well, if you have the binlogs or can rebuild the Slave, a messy recovery is possible.)  2 months?  Sound like it would be better to rebuild the slave.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my approach and partially worked. After manually changing ( with mariadb stopped ) master-bin.index the slave started working again but only Master_Log_File was increasing

Master_Log_File: master-bin.000319
Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000312
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes

As if slave was only reading but not writing. So I gave up and I will recreate the slave now.